# Can I Install Visual Studio 2008 Express with VS 2005?

Tags: visual-studio

I wonder if They can work perfectly together...

Comment: I have VS2005 installed. But I was afraid about installing VS2008 and lose everything. I think I have to install 3.5 framework first. Is that correct?

Comment: Installing VS2008 installs the 3.5 Framework.

Comment: Also install VS2008 SP1, which installs 3.5 SP1 as well. Use some caution though if you're developing a web app and the production machine doesn't have 3.5 SP1 and only has 3.5 http://www.romsteady.net/blog/2008/08/dbml-not-backwards-compatible.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes VS'08 and VS'05 will work nicely when installed on the same machine.

Now, if only they made the .NET 2.0 support in VS'08 use the same solution/project file version number as VS'05 so you could easily move back and forth VS versions with the same project without modification.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is yes - I have both installed on the machine I'm replying to this question from. :=)

Answer (score 1):

I have both running on my machine and all seems to be fine after 2 weeks of use...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they work well together.  Refer to [Installing Visual Studio Versions Side-by-Side on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx) for more information.

You may need to install VS2005 before VS2008 though, or you're file associations may end up not working correctly.